# Whiptail is not running my bash commands

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a bash program using `whiptail` to give a graphical type interface to the user to setup their system.  For some reason my script isn't running any of my bash commands though, instead it seems to be cycling through outputting to my `log.txt` file, but no packages are being installed.

```
STATUS=0
     touch log.txt
     while [ $STATUS -lt 100 ]; do
        # update apt repos
        apt-get update
        wait
        echo "apt-get update" >> log.txt
        let STATUS=STATUS+15
        echo $STATUS
        # update apt package
        apt-get upgrade
        wait
        echo "apt-get upgrade" >> log.txt
        let STATUS=STATUS+15
        echo $STATUS
        # install required packages
        apt-get -y git-all nmap hydra
        wait
        echo "apt-get -y git-all nmap hydra" >> log.txt
        let STATUS=STATUS+10
        echo $STATUS
        # install rbenv
        git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
        wait
        echo "cloning rbenv" >> log.txt
        echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
        echo 'exporting PATH' >> log.txt
        ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
        wait
        echo 'initializing rbenv' >> log.txt
        git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
        wait
        echo "cloning ruby-build" >> log.txt
        rbenv install 2.1.4
        wait
        echo "installing ruby 2.1.4" >> log.txt
        let STATUS=STATUS+25
        echo $STATUS
      done | whiptail --gauge "Setting Up Neo (THIS WILL TAKE SOME TIME)..." 40 78 0
```

So, to confirm my while loop is actually running, I started echoing things to `log.txt`.  Here is the output:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get -y git-all nmap hydra
cloning rbenv
exporting PATH
initializing rbenv
cloning ruby-build
installing ruby 2.1.4
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you have no backgrounded processes, `wait` is not doing anything.

Second, since `whiptail` is reading stdin, you need to ensure that stdout from all apt-get, git, rbenv, etc commands are redirected to stderr, or better, to your log.

```
    # update apt repos
    echo "apt-get update" >> log.txt
    apt-get update >>log.txt 2>&1
    (( STATUS += 15 ))
    echo $STATUS

    # update apt package
    echo "apt-get upgrade" >> log.txt
    apt-get upgrade >> log.txt 2>&1
    (( STATUS += 15 ))
    echo $STATUS
```

and so on.

Comment: That makes sense... the stderr stdout redirects are killing me!